# Django rest ModelViewSet multiple GET requests with different URLs

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

I have to Models: A Library can have many Books.

Right now I have a URL for performing CRUD on Books in a specific Library:

`router.register(r'books/(?P<library_id>[0-9]+)', BookViewSet, base_name='books')`

and corresponding view:

```
class BookViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    serializer_class = BookSerializer
    def get_queryset(self):

        genre_query = self.request.query_params.get('genre', None)
        status_query = self.request.query_params.get('status', None)
        author_query = self.request.query_params.get('author', None)

        books = Book.objects.filter(which_library=self.kwargs.get('library_id'))
        if genre_query:
            books = books.filter(genre=genre_query)
        if status_query:
            books = books.filter(status=status_query)
        if author_query:
            books = books.filter(author=author_query)
        return books
```

I originally did not use ModelViewSet instead I had functions with @api_view decorators, one of which was following (returning books added in last two weeks, I had a separate URL for this function as api/books//new_arrivals):

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def new_arrivals(request, library_id):
    """
    List all new arrival books in a specific library
    """
    d=timezone.now()-timedelta(days=14)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        books = Book.objects.filter(which_library=library_id)
        books = books.filter(when_added__gte=d)
        serializer = BookSerializer(books, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

While using ModelViewSets, how can I do it? Must I add another URL and then write another class for new_arrivals or write a function in existing BookViewSet? How to achieve handling those two GET methods in that case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend traditional viewSet by adding special methods `list_route` and `detail_route`. With this decorators you can add new urls produced by ViewSet. In this case [`list_route`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing) is more suitable:

```
from rest_framework.decorators import list_route

class BookViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    ...
    @list_route()
    def new_arrivals(self, request):
        books = self.get_queryset()
        d=timezone.now()-timedelta(days=14)
        books = books.filter(when_added__gte=d 
        serializer = self.get_serializer(books, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

This will add additional url to the viewSet: `books/{library_id}/new_arrivals`.

Comment: Thanks lot once again! Now I have a complete working example of all different possibilities with ModelViewSet :)

Answer (score 1):

`list_route` and `detail_route` are depreciated and they are merged with decorator action.

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/community/3.8-announcement/#deprecations